# Figure caption within enumerate environment

Tags: floats, captions, enumerate

My first ever question here. I want numbering of figures based on the enumerate number, kinda like `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` but for enumerate environment.

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{Q\theenumi.}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Question 1 Part (a)
        \item Question 1 Part (b)
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{imageQ1b}
            \caption[Figure Q1(b)]{The caption should be appear as Figure Q1(b) instead of Figure 1: }
        \end{figure}
        \item Question 1 Part (c)
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{imageQ1c}
            \caption{The caption should be appear as Figure Q1(c) instead of Figure 2: }
        \end{figure}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Question 2 Part(a)
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{imageQ2a}
            \caption{The caption appear as Figure Q2(a) instead of Figure 3: }
        \end{figure}
        \item Question 2 Part(b)
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle this is just a matter of redefining the printed representation of the figure number by e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Q\theenumi(\theenumii)}
```

(assuming you have just one figure per second level enumeration item, so the actual value of `figure` is irrelevant).  However, if you have figures elsewhere in you document you will get strange numbering of those.  So firstly this change should just be applied at the start of `enumerate`.

However, now the number of the other figures (outside `enumerate`) jumps over some values.  One way around this is to define a newcounter

```
 \newcounter{curfigure}
```

save the original value of the figure counter in this at the beginning of the `enumerate` environment

```
\setcounter{curfigure}{\value{figure}}
```

and then restore it at the end via the corresponding `\setcounter{figure}{\value{curfigure}}`.

[image: Sample figures]

with cross references

[image: Sample references]

As you don't want your figures to float, you should use a `center` environment and `\captionof{figure}{....}` from the `caption` package.

The wide figure numbers mean that labels in the list of figures overlap the text in the standard settings for `report`, so in the code below I have adjusted that too.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{Q\theenumi.}
\newcounter{curfigure}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Test figure.
  \caption{Test figure.}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{curfigure}{\value{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Q\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1 Part (a)
  \item Question 1 Part (b)
    \begin{center}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{The caption appears as Figure
      Q1(b): instead of Figure 1:}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{center}
  \item Question 1 Part (c)
    \begin{center}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \captionof{figure}{The caption appears as Figure Q1(c): instead
      of Figure 2:}\label{fig:1c}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 2 Part(a)
    \begin{center}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{The caption appears Figure Q2(a): instead of
      Figure 3:}\label{fig:2a}
    \end{center}
  \item Question 2 Part(b)
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\setcounter{figure}{\value{curfigure}}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Test figure two.
  \caption{Test figure two.}
  \label{fig:test-2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Test figure three.
  \caption{Test figure three.}
  \label{fig:test-3}
\end{figure}

The figures in the questions are \ref{fig:1b}, \ref{fig:1c}
and~\ref{fig:2a}.

The other figures are \ref{fig:test}, \ref{fig:test-2}
and~\ref{fig:test-3}.

\end{document}
```